# Application Web Service Control Manager detected AWEBSVC is not responding

Tags: sccm

Application Web Service Control Manager detected AWEBSVC is not responding to HTTP requests.  The http status code and text is 500, Internal Server Error.

I am getting this critical error in component Status.I tried below link to check the issue

http://localhost/CMApplicationCatalogSvc/applicationofferService.svc

This page gave me the following info

Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (270270464 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory. As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests. To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

When i checked the Sever have enough space in all drive.How i can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with drive space, it's with the Memory.

In the .NET Framework 4.5.1, an exception is thrown if the available memory on the web server is less than the percentage specified by the **minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService** configuration setting. (In the .NET Framework 4.5, this setting was ignored.)

To revert to the previous behavior where the minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService setting was ignored, modify the **web.config** file as follows:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
                           minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
   <serviceActivations>
   ...
   </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

The **web.config** file location can be:
32-bit:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\config\machine.config

64-bit:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version]\config\machine.config

Locate the file and edit, search (ctrl+F) element **serviceHostingEnvironment** and edit property value as above.

Review [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458357(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.